# Can I Use LabVIEW to call a MATLAB calculation routine?

Tags: matlab, labview

I'm still on the learning curve with LabVIEW and MATLAB and could use some pointers on something.  I'm using LabVIEW to create a small application to receive data from a digital source, perform a look-up and calculation routine, visualize the result for the user, and allow the user to control the inputs to the routine, but I received the calculation routine as an m-file and I don't want to have to recreate it in LabVIEW because it's a lot of math.  Will MathScript work for me without requiring the user to have MATLAB installed?

Or should I bite the bullet and redo it in LabVIEW?  Or am I asking too much from LabVIEW in the first place and should just do the whole thing in MATLAB?

Comment: First google search result http://www.ni.com/pdf/seminars/pt/seminario_labview_matlab.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the MathScript add-on as part of your LabVIEW installation, you should be able to run MATLAB code without having MATLAB itself installed.

http://www.ni.com/white-paper/6206/en/

I couldn't easily find any information on whether there are any MATLAB functions or syntax that MathScript doesn't support, but it should be easy enough to test your existing code and see if it gives the right answers without any errors.

If you don't have MathScript or if it can't run your existing code successfully, your best bet is probably to reimplement your algorithm in LabVIEW. Based on your description LabVIEW should be quite capable of doing what you want, and by the time you've learned how to handle the data acquisition, visualisation and UI aspects the task of converting the algorithm probably won't be much extra work.